# Why are all metrics are essentially equivalent on compact spaces?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, big-picture

In his book [Poincaré's Legacies](https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2009/01/whatsnew.pdf), Terence Tao writes on p. 215:

> Since all metrics are essentially equivalent on compact spaces, we
>   see that <...>

What exactly does he mean by that? Could someone give a reference? I had problems finding one.

Comment: On a compact space, all metrics that induce the topology are uniformly equivalent, that is, $\operatorname{id}_K \colon (K,d_1) \to (K,d_2)$ is uniformly continuous for all metrics $d_1,d_2$ on $K$ inducing the topology.

Comment: @DanielFischer: but what you say seems like: "if equivalent, then uniformly equivalent". It doesn't seem to be what Tao is saying in the quote.

Comment: @Leo If you add metrics that induce a different topology, then it makes no sense to speak of compactness in the first place. The discrete metric on $[0,1]$ is not equivalent to the standard metric, for example.

Comment: If we don't require them to induce the topology on $K$, then we have just a set (with size restrictions, a compact metric space can't have too many points), and on an infinite set, arbitrary metrics are far from equivalent. So if we don't require the metrics considered to be topologically equivalent, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: In general, metrics that are equivalent, that is, which induce the same topology, need not be uniformly equivalent. But if two metrics induce the same topology, and that topology is compact, then the two metrics are uniformly equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some properties of metric spaces $(X,d)$ depend on the choice of metric $d$ rather than the induced topology. Consider for example the question of whether $(X,d)$ is complete. Even if $d'$ and $d$ generate the same topology, it does not follow that $(X,d)$ being a complete metric space implies $(X,d')$ is.

For example $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb R$ are homeomorphic topological spaces, but only the second is complete. We could use this fact to put an equivalent metric on $(0,1)$ that makes it complete. However this would be changing the metric space.

All equivalent metrics being uniformly equivalent prevents this sort of problem happening.